# Decoupled Drupal and layouts

Tags: drupal

As I was experimenting with decoupled Drupal I wondered how modules like Panels, Display Suite, or the layout builder fit in the process.

I used Panels a lot in the past, and it seems the JSON api doesn't export rendering info, only data.

Is it correct to assume then that in a decoupled Drupal scenario, Drupal is used purely for data, and that all layouts need to be setup in the frontend app?

Are there any solutions, or technique out there to allow a customer to move blocks around, or set up new layouts, that integrate with a decoupled Drupal process?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct to assume then that in a decoupled Drupal scenario, Drupal is used purely for data, and that all layouts need to be setup in the frontend app?

Yes.

> Are there any solutions, or technique out there to allow a customer to move blocks around, or set up new layouts, that integrate with a decoupled Drupal process?

You can create fields with options. Those will be exported as data. Then based on those, you can take decisions on whatever you build your front end.

Comment: @user7695 sure thing!